Suspected failure of monitor
I suspect that the monitor has died (well part died) on one of my PCs.
The PC in question had just had the new NVIDIA App installed which replaced the old NVIDIA stuff. The PC rebooted as I expected it would but when it had restarted, there was no monitor output.
The computer boots ok as even with no working screen I can press one of the arrow keys and then type my password. I hear the sound that you get when you've logged in.
It's an HDMI cable, I've tried both the HDMI port on the graphics hard and the built in HDMI port, no display with either. I won't have another monitor that I can try until the weekend.
The monitor that is suspected to have failed is going to be replaced anyway but I need to be sure that there's also not a fault with the computer. The computer is running the version of Windows 11 that preceded the current new version of Windows 11.

this might seem dumb but - could you hold up a flashlight to the monitor? could be backlight failure, so there's a picture, but you can't see it.

Does the menu on the monitor still show up when you press the relevant button? Do you get a “No Signal” type message? If so I would be more inclined to suspect a problem with the computer given that you just updated the drivers

Get a no signal message. Can't even view the bios. tried the onboard HDMI and the HDMI on the graphics card.

The onboard graphics might be disabled if you have a separate graphics card. So to test whether the graphics card has died, remove it and then try the onboard HDMI.

Just about every monitor I have ever had has had some form of on screen display: back in the early days just to show brightness/contrast. Does that work - if not your monitor is hosed...

Tried to access the on-screen menu for the monitor, no luck, will try again tonight. Just looked up when I got the monitor and it was back in 2012

Now 100% certan thatthe monitor had failed. Managed to plug the HDMI into a way way input to one way output for a TV (the TV only has 1 HMDI port as it's a really old one) and that detected a signal from the PC.
